# Query Active Directory User and Computers for Users that have a disabled manager

Tags: active-directory

I was wondering if there is a way to create a "Saved Query" that lists all the "Active" Users that are assigned to a "Disabled" user as their manager.

Right now, I am doing a search where the "Manager" "is (exactly)":

`CN=John\20Doe,OU=Disabled\20Users,DC=domain,DC=local`

But I have to manually change it each time to the disabled manager's name, each time I want to make changes.  That is ok when I remember to do it the exact time I am disabling the manager's user.  But if I forget and I want to go back and just confirm I haven't missed anyone, I would love to be able to do a search for all users assigned to ANY disabled managers (also whether or not I have moved the manager to my "Disabled Users" OU, in case I forgot to do that too).

**I want to do this within ADUC** so that I can just quickly/easily double click the search results one at a time to change the active user's manager to the new manager.  I need to do this *one at a time*, because users could be assigned different managers.

So I am not looking for a search via PowerShell, or how to "mass change" a manager's assigned users to another single manager via PowerShell as both would not be useful in this case.

Current ADUC Saved Query string within Windows Server 2019 Standard:

`(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(manager=CN=John\20Doe,OU=Disabled\20Users,DC=domain,DC=local))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do exactly what you're looking for in one query, but there is something that you can do for the purpose you need. You can use the [`directReports`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adls/f7cd6943-872d-423c-8009-bc8502485fab) attribute, which is a back link for the `manager` attribute (i.e. `directReports` will have the users that have this user as the `manager`).

Using that, you can look for disabled accounts that have any direct reports using this query:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(directReports=*))
```

Then you can open each found user, go to the Organization tab and look at the list of direct reports, double click on each and change the manager.

Comment: Yes, this works.  Thanks.  I just never realized you could double click the "direct reports" list entries and access them directly that way.